# Is it possible to deserialize JSON to a tree in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have JSON response from Facebook, which I **don't** want to deserialize into a custom Java object. Mostly because there is no guarantee that their API will stay stable. Once they change it my deserialization will fail for sure.

What I want is to deserialize their JSON data into `HashMap<String, Object>`, where `Object` may be a `String` or a `HashMap`. In PHP it's called associative array and it is produced by [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function. Is it possible to do the same in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certainly. Have a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), it can do this easily enough, e.g.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> userData = mapper.readValue(jsonData, Map.class);
```

The resulting `Map` will nest as many levels deep as is required.