# How to deserialize from json tree?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose I have json tree already read.

Is it possible to deserialize from it (without converting back to string)?

```
public class TryDeserializeNode {

   public static class MyClass {

      private int x = 11, y = 12;

      public int getX() {
         return x;
      }

      public void setX(int x) {
         this.x = x;
      }

      public int getY() {
         return y;
      }

      public void setY(int y) {
         this.y = y;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
      String string = mapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);

      JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(string);

      // how to deserialize from tree directly?
      // MyClass myclass2 = mapper.readValue(tree.toString(), MyClass.class);
      MyClass myclass2 = mapper.readValue(tree, MyClass.class);

   }
}
```

Comment: take a look at this post may helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159194/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-json-to-a-tree-in-java

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use [`treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode,%20java.lang.Class)):

```
MyClass myclass2 = mapper.treeToValue(tree, MyClass.class);
```

where `mapper` is your Jackson mapper and `tree` is your `JsonNode`.